# Is this a BUG about the <concept> lib in c++?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I've met an "internal compiler error" while learning the concept lib in c++...

Environment:

compile cmd: `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -fconcepts -g -v| more;`

some of the compile output:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c++17' '-fconcepts' '-g' '-v' '-save-temps' '- 
shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2' '-march=nocona'
```

my codes:

```
template<class A, class B>
concept bool Test = true;

template<class T>
concept bool Ohh = requires(T t, Test<typename T::type> sth){
    { t.func(sth) };
};

//this one works well !!
// template<class T>
// concept bool OK = requires(T t){
//  { t.func(Test<typename T::type>) };
// };

template<class T>
struct A{
    typedef T type;

    void func(T){}
};

Ohh{T} /* OK{T} works fine */
struct B{
    static const bool value = true;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[] /*, char *envp[]*/)
{
    cout << B<A<int>>::value;
}
```

Here are the error msgs:

```
internal compiler error: in synthesize_implicit_template_parm, at cp/parser.c:39068
 concept bool Ohh = requires(T t, Test<typename T::type> sth){
                                                       ^
libbacktrace could not find executable to open.
...
```

Is that a bug or I just shouldn't use `Test<typename T::type>` in requires-expression's parameter list?

Note: I cannot report this bug because account creation is restricted on buggzilla.

Comment: I think any time a compiler crashes with an internal compiler error it's a bug. But it's only a serious bug if it does so when compiling valid code.

Comment: This is obviously a compiler bug. I reproduced it with gcc 9.1.1, and since you can't file a bug report, for the reasons stated, I did it for you. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91277

Answer (score 2):

Any internal compiler error is a de-facto compiler bug. The question is, should your code be valid if the compiler were working correctly?

No.

`Test<typename T::type>` is a `constexpr` boolean variable, which ultimately boils down to the value `true`. And a variable is not a legal typename inside of the parameters of a `requires` expression.

What you want in the parameter is just `typename T::type`, since that's the type you want to give `sth`. But what you *also* want is to restrict this concept to a `T` which has a `::type` typename member.

Basically, you don't need `Test`:

```
template<class T>
    requires requires { T::type; }
concept bool Ohh = requires(T t, typename T::type sth){
    { t.func(sth) };
};
```

Or, if you want to conceptualize the idea of a type which has a `::type` typename:

```
template<class T>
concept bool HasType = requires { T::type; };

template<HasType T>
concept bool Ohh = requires(T t, typename T::type sth){
    { t.func(sth) };
};
```

I think you're falling into the trap of pre-concepts thinking, where you've tried to use the usual template metaprogramming solution instead of the concept one. Express the requirement you want as directly as possible.